# My userid on Stack Overflow.com doesn't work on other Stack Exchange sites, how to fix?

Tags: support

1. When I first came to Stack Overflow.com I logged in with a Google account, and I have 2 Google accounts.
2. I went to unix.stackexchange.com and tried to use the same Google account <strike>, but could not. And I signed up for a regular Stack Exchange account.</strike> and that is what is used there now.
3. When I'm on Stack Overflow.com (using first account) then go to the unix.stackexchange.com, I'm logged out by the system. When I log in to unix.stackexchange.com, it doesn't ask me for an id, it just logs me in using the incorrect Stack Exchange account with only 1 point.
4. <strike>How do I use my Google account from Stack Overflow.com to read and post on unix.stackexchange.com?</strike> How do I use the points on Stack Overflow.com and unix.stackexchange.com at the same time? Do I have to delete a cookie or saved password somewhere? I use Firefox 29.

Comment: Just to say that you should have been able to register the google account - you didn't specify what was not working, which would be useful to know.

Comment: Please don't edit your question into something **completely different**, invalidating existing answer in the meanwhile. Ask a new question.

Comment: I edited my comments to reflect what I just found out. I'd like to see the same points on stackoverflow.com as on unix.stackexchange.com. Usually on other sites, if you log in with the same ID, my first SE account will be used on the unix.stackexchange.com site.

Comment: "I'd like to see the same points on stackoverflow.com as on unix.stackexchange.com". They are different communities and different sites. I understand you would like the reputation to be cumulative, but that's not how it works. Both can be linked to the same network account, but are otherwise completely separate.

Comment: Having the same rep on all your accounts on SE is a bad idea. Just because someone has a 5 digit rep on SE doesn't mean they know anything about cooking or aviation, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to your account page on unix.stackexchange.com (you didn't link to it, so...).
2. Click the "my logins" link at the top.
3. In the popup, click "add more logins...", at the bottom of the link.
4. Add your google login.

Comment: The account on unix.stackexchange.com is already my Google account for some reason, but my points on unix.s.com are 1. I have more points on stackoverflow.com. Do I get zero points when I start each SE community?

Comment: @Bulrush - well, yes. On each site you start with 1. Once you reach 200 on a single site, you will gain a 100 reputation bonus on the others.

Comment: Ah, there's the problem. I didn't know that.